# How can I install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 while being able to recover from an Nandroid backup?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I use CyanogenMod and ClockWork Recovery on my Nexus 7. How can my existing full nandroid backup be used to restore my device after installing Ubuntu?

[The instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) assume "recovery" would mean re-flashing the vanilla image, at factory, data-wiped condition.

It would be useful to provide a .zip that can be flashed via Clockwork (or other) recovery usin ROM Manager or booting into recovery and back to whatever Nandroid backup there is - much as any other ROM is provided/used.

Comment: This is likely off-topic for this forum. This is really an Android/hack question, and better suited to **XDA Developers**, or similar.

Comment: Given Canonical is actively blogging about this and directing questions about Ubuntu on Android devices (http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/11/13/ubuntu-core-desktop-on-the-nexus-7-getting-involved/), I believe this is appropriate here.

Comment: Probably more suited to the Android Enthusiasts SE http://android.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install Google Nexus 7 Toolkit version 3.2.x (find in xda:nexus 7:Android dev)
2. Choose your android version (or former version in this case)
3. Choose option 9, "Download, Extract, and Flash Google Factory Stock ROM"
4. Put your device in FASTBOOT by holding volume down and the power button
5. This will format your device to a factory state
6. Choose option 6 now, "Flash Recovery"
7. Choose either CWM or TWRP
8. Push your nandroid backup back to your device (just using regular methods)
9. Boot into Recovery
10. Flash your backup
11. you can also do this from the command line using android tools

I have done this twice now from Ubuntu installs, works fine

Answer (score 3):

The official Canonical answer is that due to legal concerns, Canonical will not be supporting, promoting, or providing any directions for rooting the device or using Clockworkmod/ROM manager/nandroid.

However, the rest of the community should feel free to jump in and come up with some directions here.

Comment: I hope someone in the community can provide another "unofficial" answer, then.