# How do I re-install Android on Nexus 7 after having Ubuntu on it?

Tags: nexus-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t return to stock Android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211987/cant-return-to-stock-android)
>   [How can I install Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 while being able to recover from an Nandroid backup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216977/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-my-nexus-7-while-being-able-to-recover-from-an-nandr)

I had Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 and now I can't return my Nexus 7 back to original. How do I reinstall Android Jelly Bean back on Nexus 7?